# Can i create an API inside Android App so server can call this API

Tags: android, api, server, communication

I need server to call this API in my android app, i want to achieve the opposite of what is commonly used where an android app calls API in server. Can i do this? Do you have any tutorials to recommend?

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: i just need server to send me a message

Comment: you don't need any api server , you can use firebase Cloud messaging easily ... 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: the app is connected to a local server, i need not have any delay.